# Is there a trick to get these 3 elements on align?

Tags: css

I have 3 divs on an ASP .Net page. I want to align the 3 boxes to the left. I want to center the button and the light blue box on the bottom.

In the picture below, the orange lines represent the "unwanted space".

This is the HTML / CSS behind the page.

```
    <style>
        .flexContainer{
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:row;
            justify-items:flex-start;
        }
    </style>
```

```
    <asp:Panel ID="UnitSearchPanel" runat="server" Visible="true" CssClass="panel">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:#800020;color:antiquewhite">
            <div class="flexContainer">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="searchByUnitradio" runat="server" ToolTip="Select Criteria to Search">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Asset Id" Value="asset" Selected="True"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Serial No" Value="serialnum" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Storage Location" Value="storageyardid"/>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Lease Id" Value="lease" />
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="background-color:#800020;color:antiquewhite">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="border:dotted;border-color:black;">
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="searchByUnit" runat="server"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="alert-info" ID="txtOutput" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn" OnClick="SubmitSearch" />
    <asp:Panel runat="server" Visible="true" ID="SearchResults">
        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            CssClass="panel"
            Theme="Glass"
            KeyFieldName="AssetId">
    </asp:Panel
```

Edit: Adding rendered HTML

```
<textarea name="ctl00$MainContent$txtOutput" rows="2" cols="20" id="MainContent_txtOutput" class="alert-info">
</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" value="Submit" class="btn" />
    <div id="MainContent_SearchResults">
    
        <table class="dxgvControl_Glass panel dxgv" id="MainContent_grdResult" style="border-collapse:separate;">
        <tr>
            <td><table id="MainContent_grdResult_DXMainTable" class="dxgvTable_Glass" oncontextmenu="return ASPx.GVContextMenu(&#39;MainContent_grdResult&#39;,event);" style="width:100%;empty-cells:show;">
                <tr id="MainContent_grdResult_DXHeadersRow0">
                    <td id="MainContent_grdResult_col0" title="Click to see Inspections" class="dxgvHeader_Glass" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>#</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td><td id="MainContent_grdResult_col1" class="dxgvHeader_Glass" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Asset Id</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td><td id="MainContent_grdResult_col2" class="dxgvHeader_Glass" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Lease Id</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td><td id="MainContent_grdResult_col3" class="dxgvHeader_Glass" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sale Id</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td><td id="MainContent_grdResult_col4" class="dxgvHeader_Glass" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Org Id</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td><td id="MainContent_grdResult_col5" class="dxgvHeader_Glass" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Picture Url</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td><td id="MainContent_grdResult_col6" class="dxgvHeader_Glass" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Height</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td><td id="MainContent_grdResult_col7" class="dxgvHeader_Glass" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Width</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td><td id="MainContent_grdResult_col8" class="dxgvHeader_Glass" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;border-right-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Length</td><td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr><tr id="MainContent_grdResult_DXEmptyRow" class="dxgvEmptyDataRow_Glass">
                    <td class="dxgv" colspan="9" style="border-bottom-width:0px;"><div>
                        No data to display
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
            </table><table id="MainContent_grdResult_LP" class="dxgvLoadingPanel_Glass" style="left:0px;top:0px;z-index:30000;display:none;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="dx" style="padding-right:0px;"><img class="dxlp-loadingImage dxlp-imgPosLeft" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_85-0O1lo" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle;" /></td><td class="dx" style="padding-left:0px;"><span id="MainContent_grdResult_TL">Loading&hellip;</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table><div id="MainContent_grdResult_LD" class="dxgvLoadingDiv_Glass" style="display:none;z-index:29999;position:absolute;">

            </div><img id="MainContent_grdResult_IADD" class="dxGridView_gvDragAndDropArrowDown_Glass" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_85-0O1lo" alt="Down Arrow" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;top:-100px;" /><img id="MainContent_grdResult_IADU" class="dxGridView_gvDragAndDropArrowUp_Glass" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_85-0O1lo" alt="Up Arrow" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;top:-100px;" /><img id="MainContent_grdResult_IADL" class="dxGridView_gvDragAndDropArrowLeft_Glass" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_85-0O1lo" alt="Left Arrow" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;top:-100px;" /><img id="MainContent_grdResult_IADR" class="dxGridView_gvDragAndDropArrowRight_Glass" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_85-0O1lo" alt="Right Arrow" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;top:-100px;" /><img id="MainContent_grdResult_IDHF" class="dxGridView_gvDragAndDropHideColumn_Glass" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_85-0O1lo" alt="Hide" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;top:-100px;" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[image: Divs on page]

Comment: if you want button to center than set it's parent class CSS to ```text-align:center```

Comment: I am unsure how as pages are rendered but if it's look like a HTML in browser than could you share that code snippet

Comment: @abhi. In your code there is no element for textarea and submit button.
Please check and share the correct code or you can share the HTML code in the view source or copy the element in the inspector.

Comment: @alex I have shared the rendered HTML from the browser.

Comment: @abhi thank you for your edition, and I have checked, but it's not enough for fixing this issue. please copy the html of parent element so we can check the full structure as same as you shared image, please check what I can see on my side. https://i.imgur.com/5dtyKED.png

Comment: @alex The ``<asp:Panel>`` is the parent element.

Comment: I see, could you add code snippet with html and css, so it would be great for fixing the issue.

Comment: @alex are you referring to the rendered HTML in the browser or the ASPX page?